# Recursion for combinations of objects but with limited spaces

Tags: object, recursion, combinations

In Python, I'm trying to develop a recursive for loop that can produce a list of lists with X objects in Y combinations.  For instance, if X= 26 (say the alphabet) and Y=5 (length of word), I need to generate a list of all possible 5 letter words.  The program is not using letters, however, it's using objects that are already in a list X long.  Any suggestions?

I presume I need a repetitive counter for Y and an iterative recursive for loop for X, but I keep getting hung up on the details.  I've tried drawing it out on paper, but the recursive nature is making my head hurt.

Edit:  Per the answer below, I developed the following script that does not require recursion:

```
list1 = ["v", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"]

def combo(object_list, spots):
    pool = len(object_list)
    total = pool**spots
    permlist = list()
    wordlist = list()
    z = []
    for i in range(total):  
        print("top", wordlist) 
        wordlist = []
        z = base(i,pool,spots)
        for q in z:  
            j=-1
            for a in object_list:
                j+=1
                if int(q) == int(j):
                    wordlist.append(a)
        permlist.append(wordlist)
    return permlist


def base(number, base, digits):
    remainder = []
    result = [0,0]
    while number >0:
        dividend = number // int(base)
        remainder.append(str(number % int(base)))
        number = dividend
        result = list(reversed(remainder))
    while len(result) < digits:
        result.insert(0,0)
    return result

print (combo(list1,4))
```

Comment: Do you allow repetition in the results? Using your 5 letter word analogy, would "AAAAA" be a valid word?

Comment: Ideally no, but I could filter it out in a separate function if it kept the code simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to generate all the possibilities here requires only one loop, and no recursion.

You can think of this as a simple problem in counting. Using your analogy, we can think of a 5 letter word as a 5-digit number in base 26. The number of possible results for this example, would be 26<sup>5</sup>. 26<sup>5</sup> = 11,881,376. So, we count from 0 to 11,881,376, then convert each value to base 26, and treat each base-26 digit as an index into (in this case) the alphabet.

In your case, the number of digits and the base are both probably different (and it sounds like the "base" you're using may not be a constant either), but neither of those poses a particularly difficult problem.

Based on your comments, you only want "numbers" in which each digit is unique. Given how easy it is to just generate all the combinations (simple counting) it's probably easiest to generate every number in the computed range, then filter out any that have repeated "digits".

Comment: This took some work to keep the parameters as variables, but I got it to work!  Thank you for your help.  I posted my code in the original question.